# android : issuse in getting started with emulator in windows8

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

--Unable to find non empty system images folders for AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google--

Again and again i m getting this error..
can you tell a solution?

Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google'
emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.
Weird, the AVD's config.ini file is malformed. Try re-creating it.

Comment: have updated video card?

Comment: may be you can try re-downloading the images for emulator?